# Download dependencies to local repository but not to "target" one

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a project, that has `pom.xml` and depends on lots of dependencies from outside (located far-far in internet..).

So, I want to download all those dependencies which I depend on to my "local repository".

This is my try (I do not need do compilation, so I use "validate" here. So I'm do not expect to have "target" folder in the end):

```
mvn validate -Dmaven.repo.local=C:\my\.m2\repository dependency:copy-dependencies
```

In the end - yes I have many dependencies been downloaded to `"C:\my\.m2\repository"`, but some of them went to: `C:\projects\myProject\java\trunk\target\dependency`, like these ones:

```
junit-4.8.1.jar
log4j-1.2.8.jar
mockito-all-1.8.2.jar
```

**Question is:** how to make those to be downloaded to `"C:\my\.m2\repository"` but not to `"target"` of my project?

For now, because of that, another projects that depend on that are failing while building, because they are expecting to find "junit-4.8.1.jar" in local repo.

**Another try:**

```
mvn validate -Dmaven.repo.local=C:\my\.m2\repository dependency:resolve
```

Then those dependencies are not resolvable at all.

> Could not resolve dependencies for project bla-bla-SNAPSHOT: The
>   following artifacts could not be resolved:
>   commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4, log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.8,
>   junit:junit:jar:4.8.1: Could not find artifact
>   commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4 -> [Help 1]

Comment: Why do you need to specify a special repo just for this? Why isn't the standard Maven repo in "~/.m2/repository" not ok. (~ is there to say it's your user home folder whether in Windows or Linux)

Comment: I found answer.. I just need to repeat doing "...dependency:resolve" until it finally download everything. Maybe remote Repo is not stable.. Not sure. Anyway I made a script that do this automatically - repeats downloading.. increasing the period between tries.

Comment: @LeeMeador because I do not want to use/play my normal repo. I just test that when have empty repo I still able to get all dependencies i need to build application offline. Kind of offline-test.

Answer (score 1):

Maven did that because you invoked the goal dependency:copy-dependencies. It will copy the dependencies of the current module to

```
 ${project.build.directory}/dependency
```

See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html

I really can't imagine these dependencies did not get into your local repo. Fiddling around with a script may not be the solution to your problem. Try

```
 mvn process-resources -U -Dmaven.repo.local=C:\my\.m2\repository
```

The -U option forces a download of all dependencies. I suggest using `process-resources`, although as of my understanding `validate` should be fine, too.