# why does maven goes and downloads same jars all the time from the remote repo

Tags: maven-2, maven-3

When I start:

```
mvn validate -Dmaven.repo.local=C:\my\.m2\repository dependency:resolve
```

I got list of jar to be downloading.

```
Downloading: http://nexus-bla-bla.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/release/junit/junit/4.8.2/junit-4.8.2.pom
```

Then next time I repeat my step and maven AGAIN downloading same pom/jar

So, I spend 2 minutes all the time even though there is nothing to download actually.

Why it happens?
What should I do to just download all deps to my local repo when it's necessary only?

Comment: Are you sure its the exact same files? Not different versions or additional files needed as you change things.

Comment: It will do this if you delete the local maven repo.

Comment: If I will do this (repeating my mvn validate) during while day, it seems I will never end. It will all the time downloads something.

Comment: "something" or "the same thing"?

Comment: something... I guess it is because it fails and then it manages to get more and more deps/things-to-download  while I restart my command. 
There is related issue, maybe be you will look at that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153611/download-dependencies-to-local-repository-but-not-to-target-one

Comment: Have you simply tried: mvn validate

Comment: if simply "mvn validate" then it will download "something" but not everything, but shows "SUCCESS". Then It takes then only 10 seconds to download. But I have lots of dependencies to download.